# Azure AD: will our OAuth2 access/refresh tokens be invalidated by an expiring client secret/key?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

OAuth2 client secrets/keys in Azure AD are issued for 1 and 2 years. This means that approximately in a year our secrets/keys will expire. We're very worried that that will break the "refresh token" step and our service will stop working for hundreds of our active users who have authorized Yoxel to access their Office 365 accounts. This is a huge problem for us as many of our clients are enterprise users that don’t want to be bothered with requests for re-authorizations. Our service runs in background and they pretty much forget that it exists.

Could you please comment on this topic? Is there a way for us to ensure that our existing users for whom we have OAuth2 access/refresh tokens now won't have to re-authorize Yoxel to access their accounts again when we generate a new secret/key for our client-id?

Thank you.

Comment: it is now possible to chose an infinite expiration date from the [New Portal](http://portal.azure.com). It’s actually not infinite but it sets a date very far in the future (12/31/2299).

Comment: Thank you Nan. We'll check it out. Can we safely change an existing secret's expiration date?

Comment: No , currently you can't change an existing secret's expiration date

Answer (score 1):

Please read here to learn a ton more about Azure Active Directory's [Configurable Token Lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

If you check out the section on confidential clients you will see the following:

> ***Token lifetimes with confidential client refresh tokens***
>
> Confidential clients are applications that can securely store a client
>   password (secret). They can prove that requests are coming from the
>   client application and not from a malicious actor. For example, a web
>   app is a confidential client because it can store a client secret on
>   the web server. It is not exposed. Because these flows are more
>   secure, the default lifetimes of refresh tokens issued to these flows
>   is until-revoked, cannot be changed by using policy, **and will not be
>   revoked on voluntary password resets**.

So the token you generated will continue to work, independent of the lifetime of the secret used to originally generate it, and as long as the access/refresh token is valid.

Comment: Shawn, thank you for the response. I am still concerned because the token refresh request includes the secret as a parameter -
 grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token={the current RefreshToken in your applications cache}&client_id={your application’s client id in AAD}&client_secret={your application’s client secret}&resource={Uri of the API}  Would it work if the secret has expired? Or will it work just fine an updated secret?

Comment: I have not tested this myself, but I have a strong suspicion that an expired secret will not work to refresh the token, but a new secret **would** work.

Comment: I guess we'll have to test this early. Try to refresh a token using an existing refresh token and a new secret. If that works we're in good shape.  How can I confirm that our app is treated as a secure one currently?

Comment: Are you asking how can you check if your application is a confidential client? If so, it should be a part of your app registration. There is a property on your application manifest which says `PublicClient: False` which indicates this.

Comment: We see this in some cases which seems to indicate that our app is not considered "confidential"? >>>> Error validating credentials. AADSTS70008: The refresh token has expired due to inactivity. The token was issued on 2017-02-01T18:34:50.7464202Z and was inactive for 90.00:00:00.

Comment: Shawn, I am not finding that property in our Azure portal (new). I just see App type: Web app/API.

Comment: Your first error simply implies that you did not use the refresh token soon enough for it to expire. If you look at the article I linked above, you will see that refresh tokens have `MaxInactiveTime`. In the Azure Portal, if you click the "Manifest" button you will see the `publicClient` property. `null` is the same as `False` here. In the portal, Application Type can either be `Native` or `Web app / API`, which represents the same thing. `Native ~ publicClient=False/null`